# the only way to log into ecr cli tools is through eval

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I create a repository in ecr, the repo comes with instructions that do not work for logging in.

`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1`

The only thing that works is this:

`eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||')`

What on earth is going on?

Comment: Did you get an error message? Would you like to share it?

Comment: when i try to push an image after logging in this way it says the time has expired.  eval way works

Comment: Using `eval` is normal, although I have never needed to use `sed` to alter the output. The command is "get" login, as-in get the command you would need to login, not actually perform the login. That's why you need to eval it.